# Python 3 , Unable to convert datetime stamp to datetime object, TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Tags: python, python-datetime

Im trying to process timeseries data in CSV and count the number of time epochs, for this example epoch = 1000 millisecs

**Here is the python code:**

```
import csv
  import os
  import datetime

    eeg_record = [] 
    path  = "C:\\Users\\ary\\Desktop\\nuerosky blink tests\\backup\\process_from_backup\\blink_50px\\task_blink40000radious50px_duration_40000.csv"
    """read CSV file"""
    def get_dirs(path_):
        if os.access(path_,os.F_OK and os.R_OK):
            f = open(path_)
            row_counter = 0
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                ##print(row) 
                ##skip the header 
                 if row_counter == 0:
                     row_counter = row_counter + 1
                     continue
                 else:
                     eeg_record.append(row)
            f.close()

    """get the number of epochs based on a epoch size in milliseconds"""
    def get_number_of_epochs(epoch_size_in_milliseconds):
            initial_datetime = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0,0)
            current_datetime = datetime.datetime(2000,1,1,0,0,0,0)
            epoch_counter = 0
            row_counter = 0
            epoch = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=epoch_size_in_milliseconds)
            for row in eeg_record:
                if row_counter == 0:
                    row_counter =  row_counter + 1
                    initial_datetime = str_to_datetime_(row[1])
                else:    
                    current_datetime = str_to_datetime_(row[1])
                    if  initial_datetime - current_datetime >= epoch:
                        initial_datetime = current_datetime
                        epoch_counter = epoch_counter + 1
            print("counter: ",epoch_counter)

""" covert datetime of this format 2017-10-13 19:22:50:525 to datetime object"""
def  str_to_datetime_(datetime_str):
     return datetime.datetime(datetime_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

Im running this via Spyder IDE and using Python 3.6.2

**My input:**

```
 get_number_of_epochs(1000)
```

**Example of the data:**

```
Time_Stamp_In_Milli_Secs,Time_Stamp_Formatted,Raw,A,B,C,D,Class_Stimulia
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:249,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:249,55,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:250,55,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:250,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:250,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:250,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:250,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:251,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:251,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:251,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:251,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:251,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:251,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:252,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:252,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:252,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:252,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:252,55,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:253,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:253,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:266,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:266,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:266,55,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:267,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:267,55,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:267,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:267,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:267,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:268,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:268,53,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:280,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:280,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
1.50795E+12,2017-10-13 19:22:13:280,54,-1,0,0,-1,NO_STIMULIA
```

**The error:**

```
  File "<ipython-input-235-fac5a2a567a4>", line 33, in get_number_of_epochs
    initial_datetime = str_to_datetime_(row[1])

  File "<ipython-input-235-fac5a2a567a4>", line 45, in str_to_datetime_
    return datetime.datetime(datetime_str,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')

TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

How can I fix this error using the current APIs in my code?

Comment: str_to_datetime_(row[1]) => str_to_datetime_(int(row[1]))

Comment: @imox your solution doesnt make sense since the str_to_datetime_() functions input type is & should be a datetime class/type. Actually str_to_datetime_(int(row[1])) produces an error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-10-13 19:22:13:249'. You cant cast a timestamp to an int().

Comment: Maybe wrong function at the last line, see `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`. Your code is not reduced to minimun necessary for dealing with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following and see:

1. change your **str_to_datetime_** function to the following

   ```
   def  str_to_datetime_(datetime_str):
       return datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
   ```

Comment: @aryan did the solution work? If this solution worked, you should accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
```

The standard `datetime` constructor looks like

```
datetime.datetime(year: int, month: int, day: int, hour: int, minute: int, second: int, millisecond: int, tzinfo: datetime.tzinfo)
```